# OpenCV detectAndDecodeMulti() won't work well with ERROR_CORRECT_H or ERROR_CORRECT_M

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I was doing QR code recognition with OpenCV. I tried pyzbar, not like it's process with the border of QR code, maybe I should switch back to it.

QR code was *created* by "qrcode":

```
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=qrcode_version, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
                   box_size=qrcode_box_size, border=qrcode_border_width)
```

We have multiple QR codes on one page and multiple pages so we are using:

```
qrCodeDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
all_qrcodes = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecodeMulti(threshold_source_image)
```

However, the problem starts we got more pages. It won't detect all QR codes in one page(4 in total, same fixed position in 4 cornors for each of them). Some of the page will get all of them, some of the page will only got three. We are currently testing it with the raw data so no weird noise or scanning issues.

For example, for this page:
[A screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIboD.png)

"bl5" did not been detected.
Log:

```
(True,
('tr5', 'br5', 'tl5'),
array([[[2190.,  150.],
    [2399.,  150.],
    [2399.,  359.],
    [2190.,  359.]],

   [[2190., 2940.],
    [2399., 2940.],
    [2399., 3149.],
    [2190., 3149.]],

   [[ 150.,  150.],
    [ 359.,  150.],
    [ 359.,  359.],
    [ 150.,  359.]]], dtype=float32),...
```

Anyone got more information about this weird bug?

Currently, our solution is to use ERROR_CORRECT_L to avoid this.

Comment: file a bug. the QR decoder in OpenCV needs to mature some more.

Comment: This is going to die, isn't it? :        (

Comment: 

Comment: Don't get the full page thing! 
And maybe it's "only" a problem with the qr code generator, as the increased error correction leads into that assumption ?!